# expand tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

In TensorFlow, I intend to manipulate tensor with Taylor series of `sin(x)` with certain approximation terms. To do so, I have tried to manipulate the grayscale image (shape of `(32,32)`) with Taylor series of sin(x) and it works fine. Now I have trouble manipulating the same things that worked for a grayscale image with the shape of `(32,32)` to RGB image with the shape of `(32,32,3)`, and it doesn't give me the correct array. Intuitively, I am trying to manipulate tensor with Taylor's expansion of `sin(x)`. Can anyone show me the possible way of doing this in tensorflow? Any idea?

**my attempt**:

here is taylor expansion of `sin(x)` at `x=0: 1- x + x**2/2 - x**3/6` with three expansion term.

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

x= X_train[1,:,:,1]
k= 3
func = 'sin(x)'

new_x = np.zeros((x.shape[0], x.shape[1]*k))
new_x = new_x.astype('float32') 
nn = 0
for i in range(x.shape[1]):
    col_d = x[:,i].ravel()
    new_x[:,nn] = col_d
    if n_terms > 0:
        for j in range(1,k):
            if func == 'cos(x)':
                new_x[:,nn+j] = new_x[:,nn+j-1]
```

I think I could do this more efficiently with TensorFlow but that's not quite intuitive for me how to do it. Can anyone suggest a possible workaround to make this work? Any thought?

**update**:

In 2dim array `col_d = x[:,i].ravel()` is pixel vector which flattened 2 dim array. Similarly, we could reshape 3dim array to 2 dim by this way: `x.transpose(0,1,2).reshape(x.shape[1],-1)` in for loop, so it could be `x[:,i].transpose(0,1,2).reshape(x.shape[1],-1)`, but this is still not correct. I think tensorflow might have better way of doing this. How can we manipulate the tensor with taylor series of `sin(x)` more efficiently? Any thoughts?

**goal**:

Intuitively, in Taylor series of `sin(x)`, `x` is tensor, and if we want only 2, 3 approximation terms of Taylor series of `sin(x)` for each tensor, I want to `concatenate` them in new tensor. How should we do it efficiently in TensorFlow? Any thoughts?

Comment: I think the above attempt can be done efficiently in TensorFlow. After the expansion of the original tensor, are you going to use `Lambda(new_x, ...)` function for your `new_tensor`? I think that's what you want to do after expansion, is that yes?

Comment: @kim exactly, after getting a new tensor `new_x`, I am going to use `Lambda(new_x, ...)` for experiment. How can we do this in TensorFlow? any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> new_x = np.zeros((x.shape[0], x.shape[1]*n_terms))

This line has no meaning, why allocating space for 96 elements for 3 taylor expansion terms.

```
(new_x[:, 3:] == 0.0).all() = True # check
```

---

For pixelwise taylor expansion with n-terms

---

```
def sin_exp_step(x, i):

  c1 = 2 * i + 1
  c2 = (-1) ** i / np.math.factorial(c1)

  t = c2 * (x ** c1) 
  
  return t
```

---

```
# validate

x = 45.0
x = (np.pi / 180.0) * x 

y = np.sin(x)

approx_y = 0

for i in range(n_terms):

  approx_y += sin_exp_step(x, i)

abs(approx_y - y) < 1e-8
```

---

```
x= X_train[1,:,:,:]
n_terms = 3
func = 'sin(x)'

new_x = np.zeros((*x.shape, n_terms))

for i in range(0, n_terms):

  if func == 'sin(x)': # sin(x)

    new_x[..., i] += sin_exp_step(x, i)
```

---

Commonly numerical approximation methods are being avoided, as they are computationally expensive (**i.e.** factorial) and less stable, so gradient based optimization usually is the best, for a higher order derivatives algorithms such `BFGS` and `LBFGS` used to approximate hessian matrix (2nd order derivative). Optimizers such Adam & SGD are sufficient and comes with much less computational consumption. Using neural network, we might be able to find a much better expansions.

---

### Tensorflow solution for n-terms expansion

```
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LocallyConnected2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

x_train = tf.constant(x_train, dtype=tf.float32)
x_test = tf.constant(x_test, dtype=tf.float32)
```

---

```
def expansion_approx_of(func):

  def reconstruction_loss(y_true, y_pred):

    loss = (y_pred - func(y_true)) ** 2
    loss = 0.5 * K.mean(loss)

    return loss

  return reconstruction_loss
```

---

```
class Expansion2D(LocallyConnected2D): # n-terms expansion layer

  def __init__(self, i_shape, n_terms, kernel_size=(1, 1), *args, **kwargs):
    
    if len(i_shape) != 3:
      
      raise ValueError('...')

    self.i_shape = i_shape
    self.n_terms = n_terms

    filters = self.n_terms * self.i_shape[-1]
    
    super(Expansion2D, self).__init__(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                      use_bias=False, *args, **kwargs)
    
  def call(self, inputs):

    shape =  (-1, self.i_shape[0], self.i_shape[1], self.i_shape[-1], self.n_terms)

    out = super().call(inputs)

    expansion = tf.reshape(out, shape)
    
    out = tf.math.reduce_sum(expansion, axis=-1)
    
    return out, expansion
```

---

```
inputs = Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))

# expansion: might be a taylor expansion or something better.
out, expansion = Expansion2D(i_shape=(32, 32, 3), n_terms=3)(inputs)

model = Model(inputs, [out, expansion])

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999)
loss = expansion_approx_of(K.sin)

model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=[loss])

model.summary()
```

---

```
model.fit(x_train, x_train, batch_size=1563, epochs=100)
```

---

```
x_pred, x_exp = model.predict_on_batch(x_test[:32])

print((x_exp[0].sum(axis=-1) == x_pred[0]).all())

err = abs(x_pred - np.sin(x_test[0])).mean()

print(err)
```

Answer (score 2):

Put three expansion terms into a tensor at axis=1

```py
x = tf.ones([8, 32, 32, 3], tf.float32) * 0.5  # example batchsize=8, imageshape=[32, 32, 3]
x = tf.stack([x, - (1/6) * tf.math.pow(x, 3), (1/120) * tf.math.pow(x, 5)], axis=1) # expansion of three terms of sin(x), [8, 3, 32, 32, 3]
```

If you would go with tf.keras Functional API or Sequential API, you might make a Keras custom layer

[tf.math.pow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/pow)
[tf.stack](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack)

Edit: In the first answer, I recommended `tf.keras.layers.Lambda`, but it might not work with tf.math.pow or tf.stack (I haven't tried). You would go with [Keras custom layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers).

Comment: could thanks for your help. how could we write general function, so depends on which function (i.e, sin(x) or cos(x)) and expansion terms (2,3,4,and so on), we'll get new tensor x= tf.stack([...])? I tried custom function which takes argument for function_type and expansion terms and input tensor, and expecting to return expanded tensor. How can we write up general function like that? any idea? Thanks!

Comment: I think you can simply loop to make a list and put it into tf.stack.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this for 1D tensor as:

```
def expend_func(x):     
    p1 = x
    p2 = x - ((x**2)/2)
    new_x = K.concatenate([p1, p2], axis=1)
    return new_x
```

note that `x` is your 1D tensor, new_x with two terms. If you need new_x with three terms, you might modify `expend_funcs` with three terms. for 2D tensor, you should use `tf.stack()` which is not the elegant way but that might help.